# Advertisement and breadcrumb placement on listing page

Tags: usability, website-design, placement, breadcrumbs, advertisement

I just want to place a Google ad on the catalog page. Right now I have placed the breadcrumbs before the ad (**option A**).

I have another option that I can place the breadcrumbs after the ad like in **option B**.

Here I have two options, which one is more reliable in terms of user experience?

[image]

Please suggest me option among them or any other idea to display the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question. In this case, it is interesting to see the article about banner blindness.

> Users rarely look at display advertisements on websites. Of the 4
>   design elements that do attract a few ad fixations, one is unethical
>   and reduces the value of advertising networks.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/banner-blindness-old-and-new-findings/

According to this, people will not really look at the banner, so both options seem valid. I would suggest going for the option B since the breadcrumb is closer to the content, so it might make it more visible. Also, it would be an interesting issue to user test or even to A/B test.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you an option C here:

Mainly because the options you have are keeping the breadcrumbs near to Ad banner which might **conflict with the Ads and users will become hesitant to click on it**.

---

[image]

Comment: I like this idea. I even thought of it but above search bar, there is a header. It won't look good that advertisement between header and search bar.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, where it is a choise between above or under the breadcrumbs, I would go for above the breadcrumbs, option B.

Why? Because then the content of the site is more linked together and in my opinion more logical for the viewer. Where am I... Oh, breadcrumbs right above the content, I am clearly in a subcategory.

Plus, the google add will be noticed slightly more because it is shown first.

Comment: I agree, it's a good reason to implement option B

Answer (score 0):

If the add is not relevant to the 'category' then it shouldn't be used below of it. When you say something as a topic or breadcrumb you should add relevant information below it in order to tell the user this information is real. Option b is the right choice here.